# make `apt` cache the `.deb` files in a custom folder along with `/var/cache/apt/archives` to aid future package installations

Tags: debian, apt

We know that `apt` caches the `.deb` files in `/var/cache/apt/archives`. How can we alter this behaviour and make it additionally cache in a custom folder also, say, `~/localrepo` so that we need not copy-paste from `/var/cache/apt/archives` every time in order to preserve the `.deb` files for future package installations?

Comment: Is there a specific need to copy the packages elsewhere, or would preventing them being removed be good enough?

Comment: @StephenKitt I have two systems. So those packages that I install in can be replicated to another just by copying the debs..

Comment: @RomeoNinov the link that you have mentioned changes the cache path. But I thought of adding another path along with the default one.

Comment: @VrajarajaGovindaDas I gathered as much; but why do you need a local copy? What’s wrong with copying the files from `/var/cache/apt/archive` to the other system?

Comment: I'd recommend using a caching apt proxy -- or hell, even a caching https proxy -- especially if you're planning on upgrading a lot of systems.

Comment: Mr. Stephen Kitt, Yes. I agree. I think this kind of automation is unnecessary. Maybe I can just change the cache path as suggested by @RomeoNinov. Thanks all for your time and support.